# Python module that allows mouse movements in DirectX

Tags: python, directx, mouse, directinput

Does anyone know of a Python module that can move the mouse while in a directX game?

I have tried Ctypes and Hammonds win32 module and they don't work in directX due to DirectInput blocking normal python modules from accessing the mouse.

Is there a workaround or a module that does this using HID emulation?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the DirectPython 11 API has what you are looking for.
[DirectPython 11](http://directpython11.sourceforge.net/)

The core d3d11 module has a method called [setCursorPos(int x, int y)](http://directpython11.sourceforge.net/docs/d3d11.html#d3d11.setCursorPos)

Comment: How will setting the cursor in one process affect the other process? Maybe I need to spawn the first DirectX process from within my python Python script and control the mouse position that way...